# Form validating through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a form validation webpage, and when I try to see if the password is less than 6 chars or more than 16 chars, it's just not working, there's no err in the console either.

My code:

```
let passwordd = document.getElementsByClassName('passwordd')[0];
```

```
if(!passwordd.classList.contains('is-invalid')) {
        if(passwordd.length < 6 || passwordd.length > 16){
            passwordd.classList.toggle('is-invalid');
            errMsg.innerText = "Password must be at least 6 characters and not more than 16 characters.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use HTML5's built-in `<input />` validation attributes? That way you don't need your users to have JavaScript enabled to get validation messages. e.g. `<input type="password" minlength="6" maxlength="16" required />`

Comment: Also, you haven't posted where you bind ("wire-up") this code to the form or input's events.

Comment: You are checking the length of an element ( an object ) . You need to check the length of the input's  value.

Comment: There is a submit button, and when the user clicks on it, this should run. I have another set of if statements which check if the input values are empty.. those work

Comment: Ohhh gotcha so I need to do something like `var value = input.value;` and `if(value.length > 16)`?

Comment: Yes, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the length of an element ( an object ). You need to check the length of the input's value.

Also you can use querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName(class)[0].
And again, you should use `const` instead of `let` because you won't be reassigning the value of the variable ( i guess )

see below

```js
const passwordd = document.querySelector('.passwordd')
const button = document.querySelector('.submit')

button.onclick = () => {
    console.log(typeof passwordd, passwordd.length) // not good
  console.log(passwordd.value, passwordd.value.length)
  if (passwordd.value.length < 6 || passwordd.value.length > 16) {
        console.log("NOT valid")
      // do your stuff
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="passwordd" type="password" />
<button class="submit">
  Click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use input patterns for validation. I found them so much time saving.
For example:

```
<input type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{6,16}">
```

this means:
it can include chars either upper/lower case and numbers and value length between 6 and 16. You can add more and it has a lot of options.
They are so useful especially when you are doing a big strict validation that you don't have to write a massive code saying like if this do it else do that.
See more: https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/